# App localization in Arabic string reverses

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, localization, arabic

This is symbol of oman's currency ".ر.ع" . I have added this in my strings file.

The issue is when I use

```
NSLocalizedString("oman", comment: "")
```

The symbol returned is reversed like this "ر.ع." .

I tried other arabic strings and they all work fine. But only this doesn't.

Anyone faced similar issue before?

Comment: @AlanS Thank you for your wise words. When I said other arabic strings are fine, it means localization file is set to arabic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's the issue with this symbol. I had to use the symbol as "ر.ع." and when read from file it returned the correct ".ر.ع"

Answer (score 2):

You can use Locale to get the correct symbol

```
let locale = Locale(identifier: "ar_OM")
print(locale.currencySymbol!)
```

> "ر.ع.‏"